# Most efficient way to compare lists based on their numerical differences?

Tags: python, database, list, python-3.x

I am working with lists containing purely numerical data, and I wish to compare one list to another in terms of their numerical differences:

```
primary_seq = [0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10]
    ...Code code code
primary_pattern = 2^2^1^2^1^2

sub_seq = [0, 2, 3, 5, 6]
    ...Code code code
sub_pattern = 2^1^2^1
```

Given this, I would like the program to compare the sub_pattern with the primary_pattern:

```
>>> primary_pattern >= sub_pattern
>>> True
```

So, basically,

```
221212  <--- Above seq.
 2121   <--- This is a section of the above seq.
```

Comment: Good point, I have changed everything to represent lists, thanks!

Comment: Are you meaning to do doing bitwise XOR with the patterns and sub-patterns? Because that's what `^` does in Python.

Comment: Why is the primary pattern greater than the sub pattern?

Comment: To follow-up on Reut's comment, do you mean you want to check if the sub pattern is included in the primary pattern? So if considered as strings, that one is a substring of the other?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class to calculate the pattern 1^2^1^2 and define the sense of >= (which seems to be the in of strings).

```
class pattern:
  pattern=''
  def __init__(self,lst):
    pat=str([lst[i+1]-lst[i] for i in range(len(lst)-1)])[1:-1]
    self.pattern=pat.replace(', ','^')
  def __repr__(self): return  self.pattern
  def __ge__(self,other): return (other.pattern in self.pattern)

 >>>primary_pattern =pattern(primary_seq) 
 >>>sub_pattern = pattern(sub_seq)
 >>>sub_pattern
 2^1^2^1
 >>>primary_pattern >= sub_pattern
 True
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the sum of differences is greater in one list than another to mean >= then you can zip up the list with itself and sum the differences...

```
>>> primary_pattern = [abs(a-b) for a,b in zip(primary_seq[1:], primary_seq[:-1])]
>>> sub_pattern = [abs(a-b) for a,b in zip(sub_seq[1:], sub_seq[:-1])]
>>> sum(primary_pattern[1:-1]) >= sum(sub_pattern)
True
```

Note: If sequences are strictly ordered then you don't need the `abs()`.